# How to pass multiple parameters in Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

In Nuxt.js if I have in `pages/posts/_id.vue` this code:

```
<template>                                                                                                                                                              
  <div>                                                                                                                                                                 
    Post id: {{$route.params.id }}                                                                                                                                    
  </div>                                                                                                                                                                
</template>
```

When I type in the URL: `http://localhost:3000/posts/123`, it displays **Post id: 123**.

So I learned how to pass one parameter through the URL.
But I want to pass also the category to which the post belongs to and display a message like this one: **Post id: 123. Category: News**.

- How can I structure the posts folder and get the result I want?
- And how to access the URL in this case? Something like `http://localhost:3000/posts/123`/News` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [Dynamic Nested Routes](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#dynamic-nested-routes) in the documentation. Your directory structure should look like this:

```
posts/
--| _category/
-----| _id.vue
```

The URL will be `http://localhost:3000/posts/news/123`.

You can access the category parameter with `{{ $route.params.category }}`.